# как подключить mysql и mongodb базы данных в yii2 одновремено

Tags: yii2

Собственно вот в этом и весь вопрос ну разве что ещё как их юзать к примеру crud модели и Active Record в гугле пытался найти инфу но не особо нашел. Ссылки и цыки только приветствуются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расширение лежит тут "yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "~2.1.0"
Конфигурация для юии, обычно web.php

```
 return [
//....
'components' => [
    'mongodb' => [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://developer:password@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
    ],
],
```

];

```
 $result = Yii::$app->mongodb->createCommand(['listIndexes' =>'some_collection'])->execute();

 // execute query (find):
$cursor = Yii::$app->mongodb->createCommand(['projection' => ['name' => true]])->query('some_collection');

 // execute batch (bulk) operations:
 Yii::$app->mongodb->createCommand()
     ->addInsert(['name' => 'new'])
     ->addUpdate(['name' => 'existing'], ['name' => 'updated'])
     ->addDelete(['name' => 'old'])
     ->executeBatch('customer');
информация взята с источника https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb
```